Is there a way to repeat an account name, given a table within a list causes an overflow page break in SSRS?
Paginated Report Layout Template that exports to PPT
I'm trying to create a Paginated Report in Microsoft Power BI Report Builder.  The paginated report will iterate through each account and export slides according to the layout in the picture provided.  My biggest frustration is that the Account Name must repeat across each page when the Opportunity Tablix causes overflow page breaks, but do not show the sub reports.
I've tried putting the entire thing within a tablix, setting the static row members to repeat on each page, but I do not want the sub reports to repeat.  I've tried putting the account name within a text box and repeating with property set to the table but that doesn't work either.
This has been a huge hurdle for me that I cannot figure out.

How about putting a TextBox in the header and setting it to the Account Name?

By doing this, you can only use First(Account Name).  So when I run this for a person that has multiple accounts, the list will iterate through each account but the header will only show the first option.

Have you tried the Grouping Advanced Mode and setting the first (Static) group's RepeatOnNewPage to True?

Yup, so this doesn't work because the Static object will need to be within the same table as the opportunity and account name data.  So my sub reports that sit inbetween them must use the same settings and I do not want them to repeat every page.  I'm really starting to think I've hit an SSRS limitation.
